# Static realization of Stack not working properly

Tags: c

I have to make a program on C, that allows the user to enter a stack of float numbers and then the progmar should print the stack. I tried to make it work, but it looks I'm messing up something, because It returns all the elements of the stack correctly, but also returns "The stack is empty" "The elements of the stack are: 0.0000" after all the other elements that are different from 0 on the screen...

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float stack[10];
int top=-1;
void Write(float x)
{
     if(top==9)
     printf("The stack is Full ! \n");
     else
     {
         top++;
         stack[top]=x;
         }
}
float Read()
{
      if(top==-1)
      {
                 printf("The stack is empty ! \n");
                 return 0;
                 }
      else
      {
          float value;
          value=stack[top];
          top--;
          return value;
          }
}

int main()
{
  float x;
  do
  { 
  printf("Molq vyvedete razlichen ot nula element na stecka: ");
  scanf("%f", &x);  
  if(x!=0.0)  
  Write(x);
}while(x!=0.0);
  do 
  {
              x=Read();
              printf("Elementite na stecka sa: %f \n", x);
}while(x!=0.0);   

  system("PAUSE"); 
  return 0;
}
```

How can i eliminate that empty stack massage and the 0.0000 as a shown on the screen element?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that. What do you mean?

Comment: `float Read(){}` ... `x=read();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is a typo in your program. You named one function like `Read`
but call it like `read`.

The other problem is a logical error. In this loop

```
  do
  { 
  printf("Please enter differentt then 0 element of the stack: ");
  scanf("%f", &x);    
  write(x);
}while(x!=0.0);
```

value 0.0 will be placed in the stack. So the next loop

```
  do
  {
              x=read();
              printf("The elements of the stack are: %f \n", x);
}while(x!=0.0);
```

stops iterations after it reads the top value in the stack that will be equal to 0.0,

Change the first loop at least like

```
  do
  { 
  printf("Please enter differentt then 0 element of the stack: ");
  scanf("%f", &x);    
  if ( x != 0.0 ) write(x);
}while(x!=0.0);
```

It would be better if you add functions like empty  and full.

In this case the loops could be written like

```
while ( !full() )
{
      printf("Please enter differentt then 0 element of the stack: ");
      scanf("%f", &x);    
      write(x);
}
```

and

```
while ( !empty() )
{
     x=read();
     printf("The elements of the stack are: %f \n", x);
}
```

Comment: I tried with if before the write(x), but when i run the app and input some float elements followed by 0, it returns "The stack is empty" "The elements of the stack is: 0.00000"

Comment: Ok, I changed the Upper and lower cases of write and read and it runs good but after i input 0 the programs returns all the elements !=0 than returns "The stack is empty" and than again the last element 0.000000

Comment: @Daniela Gocheva  i do not know what you tried. All you need is described in my post.

Comment: just updated the code in my post and changed the question. Please check it :)

Comment: @Daniela Gocheva I already wrote all what you need. What is the problem? Introduce two functions empty and full.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a pre-defined function that reads into files. The way you call it make it to fail, thus returning -1. In fact, you defined a `Read` function but called `read`.

Standard names for stack operations are `push` and `pop`...